# Buffering or holding back frames in OpenGLES

Tags: android, opengl-es, grafika

I am trying to buffer upto 10 frames in GLES on Android. The incoming frames come from a camera to a `surfacetexture` and I process the image using OpenGles. I'm attempting to do this because I'm applying several gles filters causing the GPU to choke, and so I'm losing frame rate. (A 30 FPS camera ends up giving 25 frames). My thinking is if I'm able to hold back a few frames and implement a circular buffer I should be able to delay the frames by a fixed amount (add latency), but still give a consistent frame-rate (throughput).

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: If your shader can't keep up with the incoming frames, buffering isn't going to help you, unless your issues are caused by burst traffic (i.e. you're usually faster than 30fps, but every once in a while you get 5 or 6 frames that take a very long time). FWIW, one way to implement buffering would be to feed the incoming video into the video encoder and then store the H.264 output in a circular buffer (a la CircularBufferEncoder), with some reduction in quality due to encoding. Optimizing your shaders is more likely to yield useful results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't - you get no direct control over the window surface management in OpenGL ES on Android - you'll get as many buffers in the swap chain as the system is configured to give (normally three).

It is unlikely that adding more than three will really help improve frame rate consistency because you're tied to display vsync limits anyway.